# Using XA transactions with WebSphere MQ in standalone Java

Tags: java, ibm-mq, aix, xa, xlc

For using XA transactions with WebSphere MQ in standalone Java   I am doing below step and getting error as `xlc not found`

*step 1- Prepare the XA switch files*

For linking  object files to their corresponding database libraries. I am executing below command

```
install path of websphere MQ/java/lib/jdbc>make oracle
```

I am getting below error

```
xlc: not found
```

I  am not sure if xlc is installed in my machine.
My machine is AIX 6.1.
But I can find xlcpp in my machine.
how to proceed?Is there any way to create switch file?

If I execute 
$ /usr/ccs/lib/cpp -help

I am getting

```
1506-173 (W) Option help is not valid. Enter xlc for list of valid options.
```

Reference:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0601_ritchie/0601_ritchie.html

Comment: That article is 7 years old and refers to a version of WMQ that is well out of support.  What version of WMQ are you actually using and have you tried the instructions from that version's docs?

Comment: my MQ version is 7.0.1.My issue is with xlc not found.

Comment: Now that you have the xlc, the docs you should be looking at are here: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzaw.doc/ja11270_.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dwayne has it mostly right but I believe xlc++ also has a version of xlc.  I see in your other question that you have xlcpp so perhaps what you need to do is add /usr/vacpp/bin to your PATH.

I also tend to use grep with lslpp:

```
lslpp -ch | grep vac
```

should tell you which xlc, xlcpp, etc you have installed.

HTH